# Sum with multiple criteria by an array in cell value

Tags: excel-formula

I want to do a sumif by criteria, however I want use an array as criteria. I have found the following formula that works

https://exceljet.net/formula/sumifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(sum_range,criteria_range,{"red","blue"}))
```

However, rather than having hard coding red or blue, I would like to have a cell with "red", "Blue" in it? Is it possible to have a formula working off cell reference, rather than hard coded?

```
SUM(SUMIFS(Re!G:G,Re!C:C,{Con!B4}))
```

Comment: Not sure but on glance, named ranges build arrays like the first example so perhaps using a named range for the "red","blue" cell range would give you this functionality?

Comment: Populate cells in range with criterias you need(one criteria per cell), name this range, call it by it's name in function.

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor A minute too late! ._.